# Maven creates class files in wrong directory

Tags: maven

I just started learning Maven.  I have two java files and they are shown below

I compiled it successfully using 'mvn compile' and able to see the class files

However, I expect 'target/classes/**src2**/SecProg.class' instead of 'target/classes/SecProg.class'

Output

```
./target/classes/SecProg.class
./target/classes/src1/FirstProg.class
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong

My source tree looks like below

```
[sathish@oc3855733574 java_tools]$ tree 
.
├── pom.xml
├── pom.xml_org
├── src1
│   └── FirstProg.java
├── src2
│   └── SecProg.java
```

My POM.xml looks like below

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>java_tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>first_prog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>src2/*.java</include>
            <include>src1/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the default folder layout. Maven is about conventions..Create a folder `src/main/java` and put the sources into this folder and remove the configuration `<sourceDirectory>..</sourceDirectory>` and the `<includes>..</includes>` from the configuration...and than the compiled classes can be found in `target/classes`...

Comment: @khmarbaise  I understand your point.  However, I try this is an exercise.  Moreover source code of my client has a different source directory structure.  Thanks for understanding

Comment: I really encourage you to follow the conventions...(Also your client!). It makes life easier...